# The ForeignKeyAttribute on property "[Model name]" on type "[Project name]" is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So i tried to add a foreign key by following [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) tutorial. But now im getting an error i have looked for an anwser but couldn't find any. these are my model classes

Movie class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models
{
    [Table("Movie")]
    public class Movie
    {   
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Customer class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models
{
    [Table("Customer")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsCreated { get; set; }
        public int MaxMovies { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? LastEdited { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Movie> BorrowingMovies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must have property's name with pascal-case :

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Also, there is no need to use data-annotation in this case.
Furthermore, the types of `CustomerId` are different in `Movie` and `Customer`. It could not be nullable in `Movie`. Your foreign key must be defined like this:

```
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me I still get the same error.

Comment: and also you must define name of your foreign key in Customer Class:
bacause the name of property is different from it's type.
[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
public ICollection<Movie> BorrowingMovies { get; set; }

Comment: It seems its a problem with my database since i can't update my database even if i remove the list and the foreign key.